# How to play audio from remote file via file:// protocol

Tags: html, windows, apache, audio, uri

I'm trying to create an online audio player for a web application. Everything is fine when I play the audio file from local web server's files doing this:

```
<audio autoplay controls>
  <source src="myApp/uploads/audio/file.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

But what I want to do is to load that file from *other computer* that does not have a web server, so, I can't use **http** protocol. In that other computer I have a folder shared for every user with read/write permision.

My question is: What I have to do to play that file on the browser getting it from that other computer, without copying it to my web server?

Should I use **file://** protocol? How?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like a web page or an image on a web page the audio files you call using the HTML5 audio tag needs to reside on a webserver.

Comment: Thanks four your answer. It means then that it is impossible then?

Comment: Indeed, you need a webserver to do this.